# Как в рельсовом приложении можно сделать оплату НА Qiwi, yandex, bitcoin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, платежи, qiwi, bitcoin

Хочу добавить оплату в своем рельсовом приложении. Хотелось бы чтобы мне платили НА Qiwi, yandex, bitcoin. Как лучше это сделать? Допустим гем могу подключить, как это все правильно сделать? или может быть есть отдельный подключаемый сервис?